# How to make sure only one API call in one second from the whole app, and no other API call for next one second in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous, dio

> I have a requirement that my flutter app should not call multiple api
> within same timestamp/second. i am working with a IoT device which has
> its own server and the requirement is it cannot handle multiple api
> calls in a second and from app there are multiple api calls as user
> can do many actions in app and we don't have the control over it. How
> can we achieve this ? i tried using delays/Timer but its not working.
> as expected

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure that only one API call is made per second and no other API calls are made during that second in a Flutter app is to use a Debouncer.

debouncer.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

class Debouncer {
  final Duration delay;
  Timer _timer;

  Debouncer({this.delay});

  void call(Function action) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(delay, action);
  }
}
```

and you can use this debouncer by creating an instance of it.
`Debouncer debouncer = Debouncer(delay: Duration(seconds: 1));`
Then, whenever you want to make an API call, call the Debouncer's call method and pass in a function that makes the API call:

```
debouncer(() {
  // Make API call here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dio package, I suggest adding a custom `Interceptor` that adds all requests to a queue and then applies the desired delay when processing them.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';


class QueueInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    _requestQueue.add(() => super.onRequest(options, handler));
    _startQueueHandler();
    
  }
}

List<Function> _requestQueue = [];
bool _busy = false;

void _startQueueHandler() async {
  if (_busy) {
    print('queue: already processing requests');
    return;
  }
  _busy = true;
  while (_requestQueue.isNotEmpty) {
    print('queue: processing request...');
    final request = _requestQueue.removeAt(0);
    request();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
  print('queue: done');
  _busy = false;
}
```

Then add the interceptor to the `Dio` instance:

```
_dio.interceptors.add(QueueInterceptor());
```

Note that this `Interceptor` does not wait for the request to finish, so the delay is only between request firing. You can do that by overriding `onResponse` if needed.

If you're using `http` package directly, you can achieve the same result with a custom http client.